# cypher: not possible to access variables declared before the WITH/RETURN

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregation

I have a neo4j DB where I have the following relations:

```
(:journal)<-[:BELONGS_TO_JOURNAL]-(:article)
(:person)-[:WROTE]->(article)
```

I would like to perform a query to find, among the authors of articles belinging to the journal that has most articles, the ones having written the highest number of articles.

The following query gives the journal having the highest number of articles:

```
match (j:journal)-[:BELONGS_TO_JOURNAL]-()
```

return j.name,
count(*) as articlesCount
order by articlesCount desc limit 1

And I thought about this other query to find the request:

```
match (j:journal)-[:BELONGS_TO_JOURNAL]-()
with j as j, count(*) as articlesCount
match (j)<-[:BELONGS_TO_JOURNAL]-(a:article)<-[:WROTE]-(p:person)
return p, count(*) as authorsCount order by articlesCount, authorsCount limit 1
```

but it gives problems because `articlesCount` cannot be used in the return since `count()` is used.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MATCH (j:journal)-[:BELONGS_TO_JOURNAL]-(a:article)<-[:WROTE]-(p:person)
WITH j, p, count(a) AS articlesCount 
ORDER BY articlesCount DESC
WITH j, COLLECT({author: p, articlesCount: articlesCount})[0] AS authorWithMostArticlesForAJournal
RETURN authorWithMostArticlesForAJournal.author AS author, authorWithMostArticlesForAJournal.articlesCount AS articlesCount
```

In this, we first calculate the `articlesCount` for each distinct combination of journal and person nodes. Then we sort the records in descending order of count. Finally, for each journal we get the top author, be collecting all in the list and picking the first element of the list.

Comment: This would return the author with the highest number of articles in that journal, but I would like to return the author with the highest number of articles in general (in all the journals), among the authros of the journal with highest articles